# Copy from a dbgrid into a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, delphi

I load an Excel file via ADO. Now I can view the data in a db grid. How to copy the data inside this grid into a different connection to a SQL Server database?
Appending this data to a matching/existing table or creating the table new according the dbgrid is fine for me.

Comment: A DBGrid doesn't contain *data*. It contains a *view* of the data from an underlying dataset. If you want to copy from one dataset (table) to another, do it either by SQL (if they're in the same database) or via code using the query components and the `.Insert` or `.Append` methods it provides.

Comment: The grid is just the presentation view for a user to be able to view the data. You don't copy this data out of the grid. You copy it out of the original source, ignoring the grid.

Comment: I have also a ADOConnection and a ADO Query with the data from the excel file, but how to copy these data to a different connection on a sql server ?

Comment: As I said in my first comment: Using a `TADOQuery` or `TADOTable` and it's `.Insert` or `.Append` methods in code.